# In elf binary, Is there any simple method to get memory address from offset?

Tags: linux, binary, hex, elf

In elf binary, assuming that I know the offset of binary.
In that case, how can I know the virtual address of that region of offset?
In more detail, here is binary `my_binary`
...and I found the data `"the_key_string"` in the offset of `0x204` in binary.
In this case, `0x204` is mapped in `0x0804204` when it loaded at memory.

***Question:***
What is the **simplest way** I get the address info `0x0804204` from `0x204`?
Could you recommend me any useful shortcut in tools(`010editor` or `hxd`..)
...or can I do this with combination of `objdump` command?

Comment: I believe these addresses are randomized every time you run it

Comment: @BlackBear No it's fixed value in the binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ELF programs have a program header, which lists `PT_LOAD` segments (`struct Elf32_Phdr` or `struct Elf64_Phdr`).  These have both a file offset and length (`p_offset` and `p_filesz` members) and a virtual address and length (`p_vaddr` and `p_memsz`).  The point is that the the region identified by the the file offset and length becomes available at run time at the specified virtual address.  The virtual address is relative to the base address of the object in memory.

You can view the program headers using `readelf -l`:

```
Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x1670
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000000238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x000000000000627c 0x000000000000627c  R E    0x200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000006d68 0x0000000000206d68 0x0000000000206d68
                 0x00000000000004b8 0x0000000000000658  RW     0x200000
…
```

In this case, there are two load segments, one readable and executable (the program code), and one readable and writable (data and relocations).

Not all parts of the binary are covered by `PT_LOAD` segments and thus mapped by the loader at run time.  If the data is in an unallocated section, it will just not be in memory (unless you read it from disk by other means).

But if the data is allocated, then it will fall into one of the load segments, and once you have the base address, you can use the information in the load segment to compute the virtual address from the file offset.